# Is it possible to run Visual Studio SQL Server project from utility/batch file?

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, scripting, sql-server-2014

I want to compare two schema which are added in a SQL Server project in VS2015 and send the comparison report through mail.

But the problem is all above I need to do by creating one utility/batch file. The utility/batch file will take the path of .Sol (created above) from SVN and use the inbuilt feature of VS to compare 2 schema. Can anyone please guide me for the same.

Comment: You can probably do this with Visual Studio's extensibility API.

Comment: `msbuild` includes the ability to perform schema compare for database projects. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/2014/07/15/msbuild-support-for-schema-compare-is-available/. The sqlpackage utility may also be used to compare the dacpac build output.

Comment: Thanks Dan Guzman for your response... It works for me.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure I'm following your question.  However, if you have two files somewhere in the file system and you want to compare them using the Visual Studio Compare (aka Diff) function, and you want to do that from the command line or a batch file, you can try this: https://www.devopsonwindows.com/use-visual-studio-as-your-diff-tool/ (you may want to change the version number shown in the example, for example, VS 2017 would use: VS140COMNTOOLS)

Visual Studio is callable from the command line as devenv.exe and /DIFF invokes it in "Compare" (aka DIFF) mode.

Comment: Dinging me (with a down vote), without a comment explaining why leaves me without enough information to do a better job in the future.  Could you pleas explain the down vote??  -Thanks!

Comment: The downvote was because this didn’t address his question of doing a SQL schema compare.  The information you provided was very helpful for using visual Studio to do a file dif but wasn’t the topic of the question.